# Nginx alias and try_files to subfolder doesn't work

Tags: php, nginx, alias, subdirectory

When I put my php files in /home/tim_test it works fine

When i put my files in /home/tim_test/hmm it does not work.  Why not?

```
server {

    listen 80;
    root /home;
    index index.php;

    location /admin {

        alias /home/admin/;
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /home/admin/;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

    }

    location /tim_test/ {

        alias /home/tim_test/;
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /home/tim_test/;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

        location ~ \.php$ {

            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;

        }     

}
```

I tried editing my file to look like this to reflect the folder change, but it doesn't work, I get  403 forbidden when I visit /tim_test in a browser

```
location /tim_test/ {

    alias /home/tim_test/hmm/;
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /home/tim_test/hmm/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

}
```

Thank you! I am so stumped.  I tried over 100 nginx restarts and different things.

Edit: If I go there on chrome I get a 404 not found, I think I was only getting the 403 on firefox because I tried visiting the site so many times. Either way though, it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [very old open bug](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) on `nginx` regarding the `alias` and `try_files` directives.

Regarding your first configuration file, the two `alias` directives are unnecessary, as both location blocks inherit the value of `root` and append the value of the location.

Also, the final element of the `try_files` directives (`/home/admin/` and `/home/tim_test/`) are not URIs.

The first configuration file should be:

```
root /home;
location /admin {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /admin/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}
location /tim_test/ {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /tim_test/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}
```

Regarding the subfolder `hmm`. Except for the final element of the `try_files` directive (which is addressed above) the configuration looks fine. Which means that the problem may be related to `alias` / `try_files` interaction.

Alternatives to `alias` are internal rewrites, but placing the target URI within the namespace of the source URI probably makes the solution unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: I spent several hours working on a very similar problem, and the addition of the $uri.html to the sequence was the clincher for me. I had been assuming that was implied somewhere in the nginx configuration.